# iPhone 6, iOS 8, App Store Update count doesn't update

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

This is a small thing, but the details are where it is at. I have a new iPhone 6 running iOS 8.02 and the App Store flag says I have four new app updates to download. This was true before I downloaded all the updates in iTunes and synched with my phone. When I click on the App Store app and click on Updates 'Update All' is grayed out and there are no apps to update.

Is this a bug? Is there some way to get rid of that annoying and misleading flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Open Settings > iTunes & App Store > Automatic Downloads > Updates set to On.

Comment: Can confirm that this works for me on my iPhone 5c running iOS 8.3. For posterity, my iPhone has a different but possibly related issue where I'm unable to download anything from the App Store on my iPhone and have to do so from my computer, which this does not appear to fix. But yes, it does fix the badge issue.

Answer (score 0):

You updated the apps on your Mac, then synced to your phone, which pushed all of the application updates to your phone.

The App Store on the iPhone is sometimes stuck thinking you still need those updates, however when you launch the app and check for updates it comes to it's senses and realizes you've received the updates via another method.

Comment: Hi Patrick, even when I launch the app store app after doing the updates it does not come to its senses.